# Concatenate files depending on filename

Tags: batch-file, concatenation

Is there a way to concatenate multiple log .txt files using the `type` command depending on the filename?

For example, if the file starts with System.[Timestamp].* then I want the content from all the files that start with System to be merged in one single master file and if the file starts with something else then the content should be appended to another master log file.Is this possible by command line or by using a batch file?

I thought of something but I don't know exactly how to handle this and check for the filename :

```
for %x in (*.txt) do ( //loop through whole directory
     //here i think there should be a check if a file starts System.* 
     //and if so then type fileName.txt > SystemMasterLog.txt
  )
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR %%a IN (*.txt) DO (
 ECHO %%~na|FINDSTR /b /i /L /c:"System." >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (TYPE "%%a">>OtherLog.log) ELSE (TYPE "%%a">>SystemMasterLog.log)
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should fix your problem. Note that the output files have an extension `.log` to ensure they're kept separate from the `.txt` files being processed. Also, any file matching the pattern `system.*.txt` is assumed to be directed to SystemMasterLog.log.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be taken a couple of ways as you mention start of filename and start of file.

This will give you a master log of all files with names starting with `System`

```
@echo off
for %%a in (system*.txt) do type "%%a" >>"file.tmp"
ren "file.tmp" SystemMasterLog.txt"
```

Comment: I modified it slightly to include all `.txt` files starting with `system` and renamed the temporary file.